# Having issues with dark wakes due to EC.RTC/Maintenance and EC.RTC/SleepService

Tags: macos, sleep, macos-monterey

Usually, using pmset -g log | grep -e "Wake from" -e "DarkWake" -e "due", I get 1 one darkwake every 8-10 hours on my mac. However, last night, I was getting 1 every 2 hours, alternating between the above given reasons. Pmset -g returns the following:

Currently in use:

- lidwake              1
- lowpowermode         0
- standbydelayhigh     86400
- proximitywake        0
- standby              1
- standbydelaylow      0
- ttyskeepawake        0
- hibernatemode        0
- powernap             0
- gpuswitch            2
- hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
- highstandbythreshold 50
- displaysleep         0
- womp                 0
- networkoversleep     0
- sleep                0 (sleep prevented by bluetoothd)
- tcpkeepalive         0
- halfdim              1
- acwake               0
- disksleep            0

However I changed ttyskeepawake to 0 myself just a few minutes ago. The sleep prevented by bluetoothd is, presumably, due to me using bluetooth right now. Wifi was disabled, and so was bluetooth during this time, and the lid was closed. Looking through my earlier logs, other darkwakes seem to be from deep idle, but these ones were from standby, after a single deep idle.

The full terminal examples are:

- DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.RTC/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:96%) 7 secs
- DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.RTC/SleepService Using BATT (Charge:96%) 0 secs

Some of the older outputs have CDNVA instead of CDN, if that means anything. TCPKeepAlive seems to alternative between active and inactive, despite being set to 0, if it's not sleeping after a darkwake from standy.

Any assistance on figuring out the cause of this increased frequency is much appreciated.